# Sequence map throws an error: NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is my very first try for scala in play framework. What I really want to achieve is to take every first word from sentences in a paragraph.

This is the code that throws an error

Text is mutable.Seq[String]

```
someText.flatMap(_ split "[.?!]")
  .map(_ split "\\s+" filter !_.equals("") head)
  .toList
```

But the problem is on 2nd line. It throws an error saying that:

> [NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator]

In my humble opinion, sentence separated by whitespace will not be empty as long as the *someText* is a real paragraph with a lot of sentences.

Could somebody clarify, how this could happened and how to fix it?

Comment: You use `.head` which is unsafe. Better to use `.headOption`.

Comment: @cchantep Thanks. `headOption` fix this.

Comment: Using `headOption` will fix the problem, but will not tell you what it was. It also changes the type of the result.
Think about what happens if one of the input strings is empty, or only contains whitespace.
You should learn to use debugging (or print out statements) to answer questions like this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, I think that your regex isn't ok, see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). It will match any character with dot `.`. If you want to treat it at as a dot character, you need to escape it like `\\.`.
2. Is your `someText` an `Option[String]`? I don't understand why you `flatMap` it.
3. When you call `head` on an empty collection you'll get an exception, be aware of that.
4. If your question still holds, I would do something like this:

`val someTex = ""
val lines = someText.split("\\.").map(_.trim).toList
val firstWords = lines.flatMap(_.split("\\s+").headOption)`

Answer (score 0):

You use the `.head` operation, which is unsafe (exception in case the collection is empty).

You'd better use `.headOption`:

```
someText.flatMap(_ split "[.?!]")
  .flatMap(_ split "\\s+" filter !_.equals("") headOption toList)
  .toList
```

Comment: This explain the `NoSuchElementException` of the question, so @Dima can you explain constructively why you don't consider it an answer?